# Can't find Docusign Connector function anywhere

Tags: docusignapi

I can't find the Docusign Connector thing anywhere; what little info I could find in writing seemed to state it could be found under Admin, but not where. Please don't refer me to a video unless it's only about what I'm asking; it's an accessibility issue for me.

I'm trying to get a google doc signed by someone; apparently I either need to set up the Connector thing or convert to a pdf? I'm very confused by the videos in lieu of an actual how-to with links and words and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need DocuSign for Google Drive.
https://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-google-drive

https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/docusign_esignature/66351547828?hl=en-US&pann=cwsdp

That would enable you to sign a Google Doc directly.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign has an off the shelf product for using [DocuSign from Google Office](https://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-google-drive) apps.

DocuSign also has the **Connect** feature which provides webhook notifications to your API program when various events occur with your DocuSign envelopes. For example, you can ask to have your software program notified when envelopes are completed (completely signed and finalized). To use DocuSign Connect, goto the eSignature Administration tool and look for **Connect** in the **Integrations** section of the righthand navigation column.

Some DocuSign account plans don't include the Connect feature, so it isn't always there. Talk to DocuSign sales if need be. Remember that the Connect webhook system is for developers.